# select items from a list based on length of the item

Tags: python, list, filter

I am having a big list of items (and the list may sometimes hold 1 million items). Now I want to filter elements in this list based on the length of each item. i.e. I want to add items which are either less than 7 chars or greater than 24 chars. The code which I wrote is:

```
returnNumbers //the list that holds million items
for num in returnNumbers:
    if((len(num)<7 or len(num)>24)):
        invalidLengthNumbers.append(num);
```

Not sure if there is a better way of doing this, as going thru 1 million items is time taking.

Answer (score 3):

You want to take an iterative approach, really.

Your code can be replaced with a list comprehension:

```
invalidLengthNumbers = [num for num in returnNumbers if len(num) < 7 or len(num) > 24]
```

or, shorter and only taking one `len()` call by taking advantage of comparison chaining:

```
invalidLengthNumbers = [num for num in returnNumbers if not 7 <= len(num) <= 24]
```

but that'll only be marginally faster.

If you need to loop over `invalidLengthNumbers` later, don't use an intermediary list. Loop and filter over `returnNumbers` directly. Perhaps even `returnNumbers` itself can be replaced by a generator, and filtering that generator can be done iteratively too.

```
def produceReturnNumbers():
    for somevalue in someprocess:
        yield some_other_value_based_on_somevalue

from itertools import ifilter

for invalid in ifilter(lambda n: not 7 <= len(n) <= 24, produceReturnNumbers()):
    # do something with invalid
```

Now you no longer have a list of 1 million items. You have a generator that will produce 1 million items *as needed* without holding it all in memory.

Comment: +1. By the way, the negation of `if len(num) < 7 or len(num) > 24` would be `if not 7 <= len(num) <= 24`. I find that slightly more readable...

Comment: @mata: indeed; negating gives us the opportunity to chain and only call `len()` once. Thanks.