# Extract strings of a certain size from a list

Tags: python, string, list

Say I have a list of names:

```
names = ["David", "Lee", "Sara", "Daniel", "Nick"]
```

I want to move the list elements that have a character count of less than 5 (not including 5) into a new list called short_names that would look like this:

```
short_name ["Lee", "Sara", "Nick"]
```

How can I do this with a for loop? Where I am struggling with is how to find the length of characters within each list element.

Comment: You iterate over the list and use len() to filter out values. This looks like homework, so it'd be nice to see your effort before giving you an answer to a question this simple.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [select items from a list based on length of the item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342589/select-items-from-a-list-based-on-length-of-the-item)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an easy one-liner you can use list comprehension:

```
short_name = [name for name in names if len(name) < 5]
```

If you want it to be more readable (for beginners), use the "traditional" for loop style:

```
short_name = []
for name in names:
    if len(name) < 5:
        short_name.append(name)
```

The two codes provide the same output.

Answer (score 0):

To find the length of a string, use the [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) builtin:

```
>>> len("abcde") == 5
True
```

Since this looks like homework, I will leave it to you to incorporate this into a loop structure to create the `short_names` list.

As some food for thought, I'll add that this problem can be solved with a single line of Python by making use of a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).